# How to register assembly in Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can i insert this in razor view page

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Silverlight" Namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverlightControls"
    TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="MainScriptManager" />
```

Answer (score 7):

You can put it in the **Web.Config** that exists in your **Views folder**.  It took me a while to figure this one out hope this helps.

```
<system.web>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
    <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"  />
  </controls>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. You are using ASPX markup in your example. In razor you can write:

```
@using System.Web.Silverlight;
```

btw. check this [syntax quickref](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx):

Comment: btw. for sure you have to add assembly reference from your Razor assembly

Answer (score 1):

you can try `@using Namespace;` where Namespace is what you need

Comment: I think you are trying to use the Razor view as .aspx markup, you should look into using helpers

Answer (score 0):

To add new register in MVC, you can put in the web.config:

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Silverlight" namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverlightControls" tagPrefix="asp" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```