# Accessing entities model from other project in same solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a mvc web project and other project where I have entities from "Database first" entity approach. I referenced Entities project into my Web project as seen on image below

Structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/reKne.png

Now I created simple controller with automatic CRUD operations.

The error I get is still complaining about not having Entities referenced:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPBfr.png

This is how type is implemented in View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Entities.Users>
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had this model inside of Console Application, which doesn't create .dll file. It creates only .exe.

I created class library which stores only Model from database first entity approach, and creates .dll. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the assembly for the razor view engine.

You can put it in the Web.Config that exists in your Views folder.

```
<system.web>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
    <add yourassembly here />
  </controls>
</system.web>
```

[How to register assembly in Razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790723/how-to-register-assembly-in-razor-view-engine)